# PlayFramework returns BadRequest with content-type application/json

Tags: java, json, scala, playframework-2.0, content-type

I am facing problem with play framework where sending `application/json` in content-type header returns a `BadRequest`.
I have a controller POST method that needs a few headers for the server to calculate the right hmac value, one of the headers is content-type
When I send `application/json` as the `content-type` I get a Badrequest , it works for `application\/json` , but the problem is I need to have application/json to compute the correct hmac value.

I have tried with Curl, Poster and a Java client and I am facing the same issue everywhere, I have a test case written in Scala which sends application/json which works(but that is running against a MockController and a FakeRequest).

Adding Some code

This is how I am adding the content-type header `httpPost.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "\"application/json\"");` 
or 
`httpPost.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application\/json");`
 either of the two work but plain application/json doesn't

This is the controller Method I am calling

```
def test() = Action {
implicit request =>
  Ok("yippiie")
}
```

Also I tried both with a valid json body and an empty json , got BadRequest in both scenarios with application/json as the content-type header.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Your controller functions that are returning the bad request, specifically..

Comment: Controller method is a plain POST request, surrounded by Action{}

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing your code it's hard to be sure (you've got Java in the title, but tagged the question with Scala), but I suspect the problem here is that you are not supplying a valid JSON body with the POST request.

If you use the plain `Action {...}` form for the controller action then Play will automatically try to parse the body with the `anyContent` [`BodyParser`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.BodyParsers), which uses the content-type header to infer the format. This means that if your content-type is `application/json` then you **must** have a valid JSON body (nothing, or an empty string will **not** suffice.)

For example, with this action code:

```
def test = Action {
  Ok("hello, world\n")
}
```

... calling it with an invalid JSON body (no data) will fail:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9000/test
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

whereas supplying a valid JSON body (an empty object) will succeed:

```
curl -d "{}" -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9000/test
< hello, world
```

The reason those other forms of `application/json` are "working" is because as far as the application is concerned they're just a random string, meaning Play defaults to parsing as an empty set of URL encoded values, and the action therefore succeeds.

If for some reason you *do* want to use `application/json` as a content type but want to have an empty body, you can use the `parse.empty` body parser. If you've definitely got a valid JSON body it's probably best to be explicit about it and use `parse.json`.

Comment: Namely `Action(parse.json)`.

Comment: @Mikesname I have added the controller method code in the question at the end